# Counting the repetition of Call ID in the previous rows, sorting by date

Tags: sql

Is there a way to count how many times a call ID is repeated in all rows prior to this row or the current field in a SQL query. attached is a sample of the data table.

[image: SQL Columns]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide us with a Minimal, Reproducible Example, what have you tried so far? Table structure? Sample Data? Expected Result? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Paolo, I am trying to calculate the number of transferred calls per agent based on call ID  and Agent ID ( example attached picture). I count repetition of the call ID prior to the current field divided by the number of repetition of call ID in the whole column, If it is more than 1, then the current agent has transferred the call. if it is 1 then the agent has not transferred it.   It is from AVAYA CMS servers and i am currently with only counting number of repetition in the whole column as below: COUNT(callid) OVER (PARTITION BY callid ORDER BY EST_Start) . appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution you want is a RANK() window function. Considering If a row have a rank as 5 means, Same value has occurs previously 4 times in the same column. If your DBMS product supports window function, You may use -

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CALLID) - 1
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```